# MySQL: mysqld_safe options

Tags: mysql, percona-server, mysqld-safe

Is there a way to specify [these options](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/performance/innodb_numa_support.html) in configuration file?

I've tried to add them into `[mysqld_safe]` section but it doesn't work:

```
[mysqld_safe]
numa-interleave = 1
flush-caches = 1
```

-

```
# ps -ww -lfC mysqld_safe
F S UID        PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  STIME TTY          TIME CMD
4 S root     17180     1  0  80   0 - 26549 wait   15:06 pts/1    00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.pid
```

Please note that I'm using Percona server 5.5.30-30.2

**EDIT: 28 Aug 2013 - 08:34:**

Unfortunately I can't find this line in `/etc/init.d/mysql`:

```
# grep -n "interleave" < /etc/init.d/mysql
# echo $?
1
```

I'm able to manually invoke these options:

```
mysqld_safe --datadir=/mnt/data/mysql --pid-file=/mnt/data/mysql/db3.improve.pid --numa-interleave --flush-caches
```

but with option file there is still `default` policy

```
# cat /proc/$(pidof mysqld)/numa_maps | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | uniq
default
```

There must be some way other than hard coding these options into `init` script or manually staring MySQL daemon...

**EDIT: 29 Aug 2013 - 08:38:**

I've just tested it with Percona Server 5.5.28-29.1.

I still don't see `numa` related entries in `/etc/init.d/mysql` however there are in `mysqld_safe` script:

```
# grep -n "interleave" /usr/bin/mysqld_safe 
21:numa_interleave=0
67:  --numa-interleave          Run mysqld with its memory interleaved
215:      --numa-interleave) numa_interleave=1 ;;
777:# Set mysqld's memory interleave policy.
780:if true && test $numa_interleave -eq 1
785:    log_error "numactl command not found, required for --numa-interleave"
788:  elif ! numactl --interleave=all true
794:  cmd="$cmd numactl --interleave=all"
795:elif test $numa_interleave -eq 1
797:  log_error "--numa-interleave is not supported on this platform"
```

I've tested other options like `nice`, `open_files_limit` and they work fine so it looks like the only option is to hard-code it into `init` script

Comment: Are you running Percona Server, or MySQL Server?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I'm using Percona server.

Comment: It looks like this might have been inmplemented in Percona Server 5.5.28-29.1 ... are you running that version or newer?

Comment: I'm running Percona server 5.5.30-30.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Percona already has that option built-in.

Inside `/etc/init.d/mysql`, somewhere I saw something like

```
# numactl --interleave=all
```

When I discovered this, every time I installed Oracle's MySQL, I added that command to `/etc/init.d/mysql`.

If you want to be sure, just run this:

```
grep -n "interleave" < /etc/init.d/mysql
```

and you will see which line that appears.

I have discussed this before

- `Jul 22, 2013` : [MySQL 5.5 High CPU Usage](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46752/mysql-5-5-high-cpu-usage/46799#46799)
- `Mar 06, 2013` : [mysqld_safe version different than mysqld?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35962/mysqld-safe-version-different-than-mysqld/36096#36096)
- `Dec 30, 2012` : [Mysql slowly uses memory until it starts to use swap](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31182/mysql-slowly-uses-memory-until-it-starts-to-use-swap/31183#31183)

Based on [the link you posted](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/performance/innodb_numa_support.html), you should be able to activate those features starting from Percona Server 5.5.28. My posts mentioning `numactl` were evidently from earlier versions of Percona Server.

In light of all this, the same thing applies to `flush-caches`.

## UPDATE 2013-08-28 09:54 EDT

If you have Percona Server 5.5.30 and there are no options, go install Percona Server 5.5.28 or 5.5.29 on a Dev Server and test it out there. Check `/etc/init.d/mysql` as follows:

```
# grep -n "numa" /etc/init.d/mysql
```

If you find it, then Percona must have missed putting that option on 5.5.30 (which would be very surprising). As the quick fix, take the mysqld_safe line from 5.5.28/29 and hardcode it into the mysqld_safe invocation in 5.5.30.

At the very least, take the line you said works:

```
mysqld_safe --datadir=/mnt/data/mysql --pid-file=/mnt/data/mysql/db3.improve.pid --numa-interleave --flush-caches
```

and imbed that into `/etc/init.d/mysql` for 5.5.30 where mysqld_safe is called.

I hope that human error (Percona missing this one (highly unlikely)) is the reason from this problem and not something much deeper.

Comment: Please see edits in my question.

Comment: I've updated my question with reply to `UPDATE 2013-08-28 09:54 EDT`

Comment: I am sorry I could not advise anything other than hardcoding.