# MySQL server cannot be stopped

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, shutdown

I am using Ubuntu release 14.04, MySQL 14.14 Distrib 5.5.43.

To reset the MySQL root password, as described in the official MySQL doc [How to reset the root password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html), I need to stop the MySQL server.

Using `htop` before killing the server, I see the following related processes:
[image]

Then, as indicated, I stop the MySQL server with the following command:
`kill $(cat /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid)`.

But, a few seconds later, all associated processes are automatically restarted under different PIDs:
[image]

How can I stop the server without it restarting new processes each time ?

Answer (score 1):

Try stopping the mysql server, instead of killing the process:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

Comment: Thanks, but it restarts automatically thereafter.

Comment: could you try the same with mysqld (instead mysql) service? Some linux distributions use different daemons

Comment: `root@:~# /etc/init.d/mysqld stop`             
`bash: /etc/init.d/mysqld: No such file or directory`

Comment: try `sudo stop mysql` or `sudo service mysql stop`

Answer (score 1):

You may not be aware of this, but the MySQL service is designed to be restarted automatically.

There is a program called [mysqld_safe](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqld-safe.html). Its job is to do the following:

- `STEP 01` : start [mysqld](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqld.html)
- `STEP 02` : check return value of [mysqld](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqld.html)
- `STEP 03` : If return value is zero, [mysqld_safe](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqld-safe.html) terminates normally
- `STEP 04` : [mysqld](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqld.html) is restarted due to abnormal termination of [mysqld](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqld.html)
- `STEP 05` : If restart is successfully, go to `STEP 02`
- `STEP 06` : Terminate [mysqld_safe](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqld-safe.html) since [mysqld](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqld.html) could not be restarted

Killing [mysqld](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqld.html) only makes [mysqld_safe](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqld-safe.html) do its job.

I have written about this before : [mysqld_safe version different than mysqld?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35962/mysqld-safe-version-different-than-mysqld/36096#36096)

SUGGESTION : Kill [mysqld_safe](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqld-safe.html) first, then kill [mysqld](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqld.html).