# Make MySQL print a timestamp at each time it starts

Tags: mysql

I am investigating an issue in an environment where MySQL is often restarted, by various actors (backups admins etc).

To make analysis saner, I need to know exactly when MySQL is (re)started.

Here is the current slow.log:

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.27-log (MySQL Community Server (GPL)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.27-log (MySQL Community Server (GPL)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.27-log (MySQL Community Server (GPL)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
```

As you can see, there is no timestamp, I can only know that MySQL has been started 3 times that day, but I don't know when.

**Question**: How to make MySQL print a timestamp at each time it starts?

*For unfortunate real-world reasons I can't get every single actor to reliably keep  track of when they restart MySQL.*

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to consult the log. mysqld can tell you.

For anyone running MySQL 5.6 and prior, or [MySQL 5.7 in MySQL 5.6 compatibility mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_show_compatibility_56)

```
SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL variable_value SECOND MySQL_Started
FROM information_schema.global_status
WHERE variable_name='Uptime';
```

For everyone running MySQL 5.7

```
SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL variable_value SECOND MySQL_Started
FROM performance_schema.global_status
WHERE variable_name='Uptime';
```

## EXAMPLE (MySQL 5.7.12 on my Windows Laptop)

```
mysql> SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL variable_value SECOND MySQL_Started
    -> FROM performance_schema.global_status
    -> WHERE variable_name='Uptime';
+----------------------------+
| MySQL_Started              |
+----------------------------+
| 2018-03-19 09:10:43.000000 |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

As to why the time is not being printed, here is what I suspect

- [mysqld_safe](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqld-safe.html) starts [mysqld](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqld.html) and stays in an indefinite loop
- [mysqld](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqld.html) terminates over some minor condition

  - Out of memory
  - Too many connections
  - Accessing a corrupted table
- [mysqld](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqld.html) is started again in the indefinite loop
- I mentioned this `Mar 05, 2013` : [mysqld_safe version different than mysqld?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35962/mysqld-safe-version-different-than-mysqld/36096#36096)

I do not believe [mysqld_safe](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqld-safe.html) will print timestamps on [mysqld](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqld.html) restarts. If you really want mysqld_safe to print a timestamp on [mysqld](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqld.html) restarts, you can edit [mysqld_safe](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqld-safe.html) (it is just a bash script) and place a line in the indefinite loop that echoes the date